# Error in URL of delta import of solr while autoindexing of database

Tags: database, solr, indexing, solrj, dataimporthandler

When i have started solr and open following Delta-import URL in browser. It works fine for me.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ACE/dataimport//dataimport?command=delta-import&debug=false&optimize=true&indent=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&verbose=false
```

But when i generate same query through wiki scheduler given in the following link where the process of scheduling is explained.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

I have followed all steps given in above link for scheduling and generate the above delta query also through it.
But i have ran into following errors on command prompt :

```
2161099 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Process started at .............. 06.11
.2014 12:56:31 055
2161102 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Request method                 POST
2161102 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Succesfully connected to server
localhost
2161103 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Using port                     8983
2161104 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Application name
solr
2161104 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> URL params                     dataimpo
rt//dataimport?command=delta-import&debug=false&optimize=true&indent=true&commit
=true&clean=false&wt=json&verbose=false
2161104 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Full URL

http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ACEdataimport//dataimport?command=delta-import&debug=false&optimize=true&indent=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&verbose=false

2161107 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Response message
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
2161107 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Response code                  405
2161108 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û JNDI not conf
igured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
2161108 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û solr home def
aulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
2161108 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û new SolrResou
rceLoader for deduced Solr Home: 'solr/'
2161118 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.SolrDataImp
ortProperties  û Instance dir = solr/
2161119 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Disconnected from server
localhost
2161120 [Timer-0] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HttpPostSch
eduler  û [#/core_name] <index update process> Process ended at ................ 06.11
.2014 12:56:31 076
```

I didn't getting what is the actual problem in the URL. It is working fine when it gets open in browser so why it could not gets call properly through scheduler.

Please help me out to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: The log includes the error message "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL". This might be a good hint at where stuff is going wrong (including an extra / in the URL as well it seems).

Comment: @MatsLindh : Thanks for the reply. I have tried by removing extra slash as you said still the same error occurs. Now this tym my URL is: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ACE/dataimport/dataimport?command=delta-import&debug=false&optimize=true&indent=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&verbose=false.... Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have copied the URL from Solr Admin Web app. Note that the URL `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/` is registered by Admin web app. You might need to invoke `ACE` core directly if you are trying to invoke API.

Try `http://localhost:8983/solr/ACE/dataimport/dataimport?command=delta-import&debug=false&optimize=true&indent=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&verbose=false`